# vagrant up Does not start work

Tags: git, bash, vagrant, virtualbox

I downloaded virtual box and vagrant (but changed default path, perhaps,it's the problem), and folder with settiongs from [enter link description here](https://github.com/semmypurewal/node-dev-bootstrap), everything, as described in O'relly "Learning Web App Development", and when i used vagrant up in git-bash, nothing happens for a long time. What's the problem? console:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cnd5.jpg)

Comment: What messages are shown? Maybe you could also assure us that `which vagrant` points to your vagrant installation.

Comment: its issue https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8764 - just use normal cmd for now

Comment: in windows cmd work as git-bash, nothing happens, no messages shown, just clean after 'vagrant up'

Comment: i used  `$ set VAGRANT_LOG=info`
`$ vagrant up --debug`

Comment: and this shown messages:  ` INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0/powershell.EXE", "-NoLogo", "-NoProfile
", "-NonInteractive", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command", "(new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Sys
tem.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrat
or)"]`
 `INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...`
`DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO`
`DEBUG subprocess: stdout: False`

Answer (score 0):

in vagrant v1.9.7 bug so solution is install vagrant v1.9.6 or perhaps something different version;